# specialize template with inner class template of a class template

Tags: c++, traits, crtp

I have a Bluetooth library that defines a `link_layer` as the lowest protocol layer, that implements the link layer protocol on top of a `radio`. The `link_layer` itself is a template to allow the use of different `radio` implementations. A `radio` itself is a template too, to allow for different, basic configurations (e.g buffer sizes).

A lot of radio implementation can share some common behavior, like `buffers`. So some of the radio implementations combine a lot of implementation by inheriting from them (CRTP).

Now I need some details in the `buffer` implementation that depend on the actual `radio` implementation (`mapping` between in memory and over the air PDU layout). The obvious solution, to define that `mapping` as a type in the radio does not work, because the radio inherits the `buffer` implementation and at the point of the `buffer` template instantiation, the `radio` is thus still an incomplete type.

Recommended solution to this problem is to define that mapping as a type `trait` and specialize the `trait` for all `radio` implementations. This worked very well, because there is a reasonable default, that works for a lot of `radio`s.

Beside the `buffer`, there is a different implementation detail (encryption) that I mix into the `radio` implementation via inheritance. In one of the cases, where I need to specialize the `trait` from above, that type itself is again a template. I mix in different encryption supporting types useing a `factory`, that defines the `radio` template as result. Here is a short sketch of the scenario:

```
#include <type_traits>

template < typename OtherOption, template < typename > class Radio >
struct link_layer : Radio< OtherOption >
{
};

template < class ConfiguredRadio >
struct trait
{
    using mapping = int;
};

template < typename ConfiguredRadio >
struct buffers
{
    using mapping = typename trait< ConfiguredRadio >::mapping;
};

template < typename Base >
struct radio_factory
{
    template < typename T >
    struct radio : buffers< radio< T > >, Base
    {
    };
};

struct radio_without_enryption_base {};

template < typename Option >
struct radio_with_enryption_base {};

template < typename Option, typename T >
struct trait<
    typename radio_factory<
        radio_with_enryption_base< Option >
    >::template radio< T >
>
{
    using mapping = short;
};

template < typename OtherOption >
using ll_without_encryption = link_layer<
    OtherOption,
    radio_factory< radio_without_enryption_base >::template radio >;

template < typename OtherOption >
using ll_with_encryption = link_layer<
    OtherOption,
    radio_factory< radio_with_enryption_base< OtherOption > >::template radio >;

int main()
{
    static_assert( std::is_same< ll_without_encryption< int >::mapping, int >::value, "" );
    static_assert( std::is_same< ll_with_encryption< int >::mapping, short >::value, "" );
}
```

All compilers I’ve tried complain, that the partial specialization of `trait<>` contains template parameters that are not deducible. Is it possible to specialize a template with a template type, that is the inner type of another template? If not, what could a possible workaround look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typename someClass<T>::type` is not deducible.

workaround is to define the class not as inner type:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<typename T, typename Base>
    struct radio : buffers<radio<T, Base>>, Base
    {
    };
}

template < typename Base >
struct radio_factory
{
    template <typename T>
    using radio = details::radio<T, Base>; // Same interface as before
};

template <typename T, typename Option>
struct trait<detail::radio<T, radio_with_enryption_base<Option>>>
{
    using mapping = short;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9dd69be8512a582a)